# Open link in new window in background

Tags: google-chrome, window, links

Using chrome on mac, when i am holding SHIFT and pressing on a link it opens the link in a new window.

Is there a way to make that link open in a new window but in the background (not to activate that new window)?

Answer (score 0):

command + click should work just fine.

Comment: cmd + click opens the link in the background in a new tab, not a new window.